# HDD and SSD configuration

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, ssd

I had just bought a system76 laptop that is preinstalled with Ubuntu 13.04, and has a nice SSD and HDD setup. The problem is that the laptop's hdd comes unpartioned and unformatted, while the entire filesytem lives on the SSD. It is a very high-end laptop, and God forbid that anything happens to the SSD. Every article I look up in my research says that you must be going on a safari in your fstab and partitioning your SSD and HDD for certain file directories.
In short, I have to ask, is it okay to just mount the /home directory in the HDD, while the rest of the file system lives in the SSD? Does it really make a difference if you're coming from a 2011 MacBook Pro with a 5400 RPM hard drive, or if the SSD tech is fairly modern?

My SSD specs are:
120 GB Intel 525 Series mSATA SSD,
And my HDD specs are:
500 GB 7200 RPM SATA II

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of people running their system on one drive and their /home directory on another. As long as it's configured correctly and both drives are always available this is a viable thing to do.

Comment: Actually, I just did a Google search and MANY people have done this. Google search "move /home directory to different HDD" and you'll have all the info you need.